# Breadcrumbs on rails - List show as child of index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the the breadcrumbs_on_rails gem. I have setup a breadcrumb for:

- Root Path (within my Application Controller)
- Controller Index
- Controller Show

When I view the controller show page, in this case debts/1 the breadcrumb is simply: Home > Debt 1. I was expecting the show to be a child of the Debts index parent, something like: Home > Debts > Debt 1.

How can I make this the case?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base   
  add_breadcrumb '<i class="icon-home"></i> Home'.html_safe, :root_path
end

class DebtsController < SessionsController
  def index
    @debts = Debt.all
    add_breadcrumb 'Debts', debts_path
  end

  def show
    @debt = Debt.find(params[:id])
    add_breadcrumb "Debt: #{@debt.id}", debt_path(@debt.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `Home > Debts > Debt 1` breadcrumbs for the show page, this

```
def show
  @debt = Debt.find(params[:id])
  add_breadcrumb "Debt: #{@debt.id}", debt_path(@debt.id)
end
```

should be this

```
def show
  @debt = Debt.find(params[:id])
  add_breadcrumb 'Debts', debts_path
  add_breadcrumb "Debt #{@debt.id}", debt_path(@debt.id)
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realise I needed to list the whole path.